# Trying to return data from related models from one endpoint in Tastypie, but the related data are always empty

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm a new user of the Tastypie package for Django and have got my API up and running. I have one endpoint which is trying to return one model and its related model's data. Even though I'm not getting any errors, the related model's data is always empty (see following example):

```
{
    "collection": [],
    "first_name": "Bob",
    "last_login": "2012-11-10T20:00:25",
    "last_name": "Schliffman",
    "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/2/",
    "username": "flip"
}
```

There is corresponding data in the model (verified in the Admin console), but it's just not coming up. Here are the related resource definitions in `api.py`:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    collection = fields.ToManyField('maps.api.resources.CollectionResource', \
        attribute='collections', full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login']
        allowed_methods = ['get']


class CollectionResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Collection.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'collection'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

Any idea about what I need to do in order to get that `collection` property populated with the related data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is critical:

```
collection = fields.ToManyField('maps.api.resources.CollectionResource', \
                 attribute='collections', full=True, null=True)
```

What it is saying is to look for `collections` attribute in `User` model and then represent each of those using `CollectionResource`. In other words, you should make sure that that your `User` model has `collections` attribute. For that, your `Collection` model has to have a foreign key with `related_name`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def Collection(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='collections')
```

If you have that, Tastypie should be able to get the collections and display them in your `UserResource`.

Comment: Thanks, @miki725. After making this change, I get an import error for tastypie's `SessionAuthentication`. Not sure what's happening, looking into it now.

Comment: The error is probably happening because Django can't dynamically import `'User'`. Leave that part as before but just make sure you have the `related_name` part.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure how to interpret your statement about "Django can't dynamically import 'User'" - I'm using the `django-registration` package so I'm just importing `django.contrib.auth.models.User` in my api.py file.

Comment: Well, it gets weirder. I now get a `no module named resources` JSON error from Tastypie (not the vanilla debug error from Django).

Comment: Dynamically import is when you give Django a string and using that it is suppose to find and get the object you described in a string. Not dynamically imported is when you manually import something and actually give that object to Django. I changed the answer so that it does not dynamically import anything.

Comment: As far as the `resources` error is concerned, it means exactly that - Tatypie can't find the `resources` module (Python file) within `maps.api.resources.CollectionResource`. According to that line it says there is a class `CollectionResource` within module (file) `resources.py` within package (folder) `api` within package `maps`.

Comment: thanks @miki725 - I have a lot to learn about Django and Python. The real answer here is the `related_name` attribute. The `resources` error was made obvious after your last comment. Since I didn't have the resources in its own `resources.py` file, the import was failing. Once I changed it to `maps.api.CollectionResource` everything worked. Thank you, thank you, thank you!